# Positioning menu below dropdown

Tags: css, html

I have the following code to display some buttons and dropdown menus.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-add-btn">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-delete-btn">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Configuration <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Enable</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Disable</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-refresh-btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Configuration <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
            <li>
                <button id="btnEnable" type="submit" name="command" value="Enable"><span>Enable</span>

                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="btnDisable" type="submit" name="command" value="Disable"><span>Disable</span>

                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works okay except one of the menus doesn't appear under the dropdown.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/474/)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to put the dropdown buttons into their own `btn-group`.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/481/)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-add-btn">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-delete-btn">Delete</button>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Dropdown Group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Configuration <span class="caret"></span>

            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Enable</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Disable</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-refresh-btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Configuration <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
            <li>
                <button id="btnEnable" type="submit" name="command" value="Enable"><span>Enable</span>

                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button id="btnDisable" type="submit" name="command" value="Disable"><span>Disable</span>

                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using latest version of JQuery. Please update JQuery and use Bootstrap library to make this work.

In you fiddle, choose jQuery 2.1.0 and select Bootstrap 3.2.0 option.

Comment: Didn't seem to work [(fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/465/), have you got a working example you could share?